# RxJS - Emit value after ever n received

Tags: javascript, rxjs, redux-observable

Does there exist an operator that enables emissions to be throttled by count?

I essentially want to repeat the Skip call. In the example below I would like to Skip 5, emit a value and repeat.

```
export default function errorHandler(action$){
  action$.ofType(types.ERROR)
  /* After every n emissions received, emit once */
  .map(someAction)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`bufferCount`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferCount), which will emit once it has buffered the specified number of actions.

With RxJS's terminology, throttling would involve the first of the buffered actions being emitted:

```js
export default function errorHandler(action$){
  action$.ofType(types.ERROR)
    .bufferCount(5)
    .map((actions) => actions[0]);
}
```

Emitting the last buffered action instead would be referred to as debouncing, in RxJS's terminology:

```js
export default function errorHandler(action$){
  action$.ofType(types.ERROR)
    .bufferCount(5)
    .map((actions) => actions[actions.length - 1]);
}
```